# How to map array faster

Tags: javascript

I have some default cars `default: true` which contain the generic gas data.
Basically I want to go through the cars and if I find a matching model I want to replace the gas value and replace with the generic value.

My code works fine but seems pretty slow. My cars array can be like 500,000 records. Is there any faster way to do this? I was thinking like when I filter the default cars put them in a hashmap or something but I am kind of stuck

```js
const cars = [{
  model: 'Ford',
  gas: 1.2,
  default: true
}, {
  model: 'Nissan',
  gas: 1.242155,
  default: true
}, {
  model: 'Nissan',
  gas: 4.242155
}, {
  model: 'Ford',
  gas: 5.5125
}];

const defaultCars = cars.filter(car => car.default);

const newCars = cars.map(car => {
  const foundCar = defaultCars.find(defaultCar => car.model === defaultCar.model);

  if (foundCar) {
    car.gas = foundCar.gas
    return car;
  }
});

console.log(newCars);
```

Comment: Hint: if you had a look-up table keyed on `model`, you could quickly find the associated data. Make that table in advance to avoid punishing `find()` within `map()` operations. That is, you want `if (car.default) { car.gas = defaultGas[car.model] }`.

Comment: @tadman maybe I have a bad approach but my code gives the expected result. I just want to replace non default cars with their gas default values

Comment: `car.gas`  & `foundCar.gas` both are same. What are you trying to replace ?

Comment: @brk they are not. look at the result. All default values are now on the non default elements

Comment: You could create an object like `{"Nissan": 1.242155, "Ford": 1.2}` and inside the `map()` function you can directly retrieve the value with `myObject[car.model]`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When you filter for the default entries, don't just collect those in an array, but key them by their model in a Map or plain object.

Please note that your code mutates the original car objects, so there is little use in using `.map` and assign to `newCars`. Both `cars` and `newCars` will reference the same objects, so you might as well not create `newCars` at all:

```js
const cars = [{model: 'Ford',gas: 1.2,default: true}, {model: 'Nissan',gas: 1.242155,default: true}, {model: 'Nissan',gas: 4.242155}, {model: 'Ford', gas: 5.5125}];

const defaultCars = new Map(cars.filter(car => car.default)
                                .map(({default: d, model, ...car}) => [model, car]));

for (const car of cars) Object.assign(car, defaultCars.get(car.model));

console.log(cars);
```

Comment: I did this example but I have dozens of properties. Is there a more generic way?

Comment: Can you update your question as to which properties are multiple: the key properties, the properties to copy, ...? Can you adapt the example so that when I use it in my answer it will cover what you need?

Comment: Anyway, I have updated the code to make updates of all properties in the default object (excepting "default" itself). Is this what you look for?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a map of default cars and define getters for `gas` property in all non-default cars of the same model. This will allow to do everything by iterating over array of cars only once. Another bonus is that if you would like to change default gas for some model, it would be enough to change value within `defaultCarsMap` and will automatically update all gas properties in all non-default cars.

```js
const cars = [{
  model: 'Ford',
  gas: 1.2,
  default: true
}, {
  model: 'Nissan',
  gas: 1.242155,
  default: true
}, {
  model: 'Nissan',
  gas: 4.242155
}, {
  model: 'Ford',
  gas: 5.5125
}];

const defaultCarsMap = cars.reduce((map, car) => {
  if (car.default) {
    map[car.model] = car;
  } else {
    Object.defineProperty(car, 'gas', { 
      get() { return map[this.model].gas } 
    })
  }
  return map;
}, {});

console.log(cars);
```